# Getting Thunderbird to open tel: links with Google Voice

Tags: thunderbird, google-voice, integration

On Thunderbird on WinXP, when I click a tel: link it asks me which app to use.  How to I get it to call up Gmail with the Canadian version of Google Voice (you can only dial from within Gmail) and dial it?